# 2d Array Loop Count is not working properly

Tags: java, arrays

So this is pretty close to complete, here is the
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvPpI.png). My methods are working perfectly, so that's not the issue. The output will give the best explanation but basically I have to print a list of 4096 random integers and ask the users input for a number. With that number I have to tell the user how many loops it took to find it. The issue is that it is not counting properly. It skips numbers that are in the output and if it is not found it prints both of the if statements. I have already built this program for a 1d array, and I am unable to use an Arraylist. Thanks!

```
Scannner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] input = new int[5][1];
    int[][] arrayone = new int[4097][1];
    int loop = 0;

for (int id = 0; id < input.length; id++) {
    for (int x = 0; x <input[id].length; x++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between " + min + " and " + max);
        input[id][x] = s.nextInt();

        if (min <= input[id][x] && input[id][x] <= max) {
            for (int count = 0; count < arrayone.length; count++) {
                for (int count2 = 0; count2 < arrayone[count].length; count2++) {
                    if (arrayone[count][count2] != input[id][x]) {
                        loop++;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        if (input[id][x] != arrayone.length){
            System.out.println("It took " + loop + " time(s) to find the number " + input[id][x]);
        }
        if(loop > 4096) {
            System.out.println(input[id][x] + " was not found");
        }
        loop = 0;
    }
}
```

Update:

I have used part of the code below to update my own and now the print is either not found or 4096, here is an [Updated Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFPSi.png). Below is the changes I have made to the code according to suggestion:

```
if(loop > 4096) {
        System.out.println(input[id][x] + " was not found");
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("It took " + loop + " time(s) to find the number " + input[id][x]);
        }
        loop = 0;
```

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do. Don't just toss a bunch of code and say "it almost works, help me".

Comment: Okay, I have edited it. Please let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: There are some oddities. You want `4096` random integers, but you're creating an array of size `4097`. You're also using a 2D array, but in name only. Since the second dimension is of size `1`, `new int[4097][1];` is pretty much equivalent to `new int[4097]`. The `x` and `count2` variables are useless, since they're both always `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code has some oddities that need addressing, especially the dimensions.  This is disguising the fact you aren't breaking out of the outer loop to end the search process with your break statement, as an unlabeled break only breaks out of the innermost loop.  Assuming you create a 2D array that has more than the one dimension, you can use a label to break out of the outer loop.

```
outerloop:
for (int count = 0; count < arrayone.length; count++) {
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < arrayone[count].length; count2++) {
        loop++;    //assume first check counts as one loop
        if (arrayone[count][count2] == input[id][x]) {
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
}
```

For your second issue, you might need to correct the numbers as you fix the oddities in your program's code, but since your program only has two results (found or didn't find number), you can use a simple if/else statement to write only one output dialogue per search.

```
    if(loop > 4096) {
        System.out.println(input[id][x] + " was not found");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It took " + loop + " time(s) to find the number " + input[id][x]);
    }
```

Comment: The first part is not working for me, when  I implement it, it just prints out 1 whether that number is present or not. However, the second part brought it a little closer in the sense that it either prints Not found or 4096.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks like you're missing a closing bracket for your outer for loop.

Secondly, the problem is that `break;` only breaks out of the inner loop so the outer loop would still continue. One way to fix this is by using a boolean flag outside both loops and setting it to true when you want to break so the outer loop has some way of knowing it should break out now.

Comment: How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both so so much! I got it working! This is how I did it:

```
boolean foundit = false;         
   // if (min <= input[id][x] && input[id][x] <= max) {
        for (int count = 0; count < arrayone.length && !foundit; count++) {
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < arrayone[count].length; count2++) {                 
            if (arrayone[count][count2] == input[id][x]) {
                foundit = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                loop++;
            }
            }
        }
```